# TypeError : kollision() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a error in the class "Baum" i dont know how to fix it.
I want to code a collision so if one object of the Baum class is on a certain position , the other class stop to draw the object of the "Schlitten" class.

```
#Laden der Pygame Bibliothek
import pygame
import time
import random
#Initialisierung der Pygame Bibliothek
pygame.init()

# Spiel-Fenster erstellen
size = [700, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill((255,255,255))
# Noetig um die fps zu begrenzen
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Speichert ob das Spiel-Fenster geschlossen wurde
done = False


class Schlitten():
    def __init__(self, px, py, pscreen):
        self.FARBE1 = (139,87,66)
        self.FARBE2 = (139,90,43)
        self.braun = (104,73,71)
        self.x = px
        self.grau = (118,122,121)
        self.y = py
        self.red = (255,0,0)
        self.screen = pscreen
        self.treffer = False
```

Here is the code for the undraw

```
    def zeichne_dich(self):
        if self.treffer == False:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.FARBE2, [self.x,self.y,5,75])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.FARBE2, [self.x+29,self.y,5,75])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.braun, [self.x+5,self.y+20,24,3])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.braun, [self.x+5,self.y+55,24,3])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.FARBE1, [self.x+6,self.y+15,3,50])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.FARBE1, [self.x+12,self.y+15,3,50])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.FARBE1, [self.x+18,self.y+15,3,50])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.FARBE1, [self.x+24,self.y+15,3,50])
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.grau, [self.x+5,self.y+10,24,2])
```

---

Here is the code for the collision

```
    def kollision(self):
        self.treffer = True
```

---

```
    def movemint(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys [pygame.K_LEFT] :
            self.x -= 4

        if keys [pygame.K_RIGHT] :
            self.x += 4

        if self.x < 0:
            self.x += 4

        if self.x > 665:
            self.x -= 4


    def links(self):
        return self.x

    def rechts(self):
       return self.x+34

    def oben(self):
        return self.y

    def unten(self):
        return self.y+75

class Baum():
    def __init__(self ,pos_x , pos_y ,pscreen ,pschlitten):
        self.green = (0,100,0)
        self.braun = (139,69,19)
        self.red = (255,0,0)
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.screen = pscreen
        self.Schlitten = pschlitten



    def zeichne(self):
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen ,self.green , [(self.x+50 ,self.y-95),(self.x+0 , self.y-10),            
         (self.x+100,self.y-10)])
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen , self.braun , [self.x+43,self.y-10,15,30])
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen , self.green , [(self.x+50 , self.y-95), (self.x+5 , self.y- 
           25),(self.x+95,self.y-25)]) 
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen , self.green , [(self.x+50 , self.y-95), (self.x+10 , 
         self.y-40), (self.x+90,self.y-40)]) 
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen , self.green , [(self.x+50 , self.y-95), (self.x+15, self.y- 
         53), (self.x+85,self.y-53)])



    def bewegung(self):
        self.y += 5


    def spawn(self):
        if self.y > 600:
            self.y = -50
            self.x = random.randrange(0,700)
```

And here is the code for the collision on the certain y coordinate

```
    def collision(self):
        if self.y > 385:
            self.Schlitten.kollision()
```

---

```
class score():
    def __init__(self, pbaum):
        schrift = pygame.font.SysFont("OCR A" , 30 , True ) 
        self.Baum = pbaum

    def anzeigen(self):
        score = 0

        self.text = schrift.render("Score: " + str(score)  , 0 , (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(self.text , (550 , 10))  

#Objekt der Klasse Schlitten erzeugen
spieler1 = Schlitten(350,400,screen)
Score = score(Baum)
#Objekt der Klasse Baum erzeugen
Baum1 = Baum(500,0 ,screen , Schlitten)
Baum2 = Baum(300,-525 , screen , Schlitten)
Baum3 = Baum(100,-1050 , screen, Schlitten)



schrift = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans" , 30 , True ) 
# -------- Haupt-Schleife -----------
while not done:
    # Ändert den Wert von done auf True, falls Spiel-Fenster geschlossen wird
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True



    # --- hier Zeichenbefehle ergänzen---

    # Screen mit weiß fuellen
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)



    Score.anzeigen()


    # Schlitten zeichnen
    spieler1.zeichne_dich()
    spieler1.movemint()




    # Baeume zeichnen
    Baum1.zeichne()
    Baum1.bewegung()
    Baum1.spawn()
    Baum1.collision()




    Baum2.zeichne()
    Baum2.bewegung()
    Baum2.spawn()
    Baum2.collision()




    Baum3.zeichne()
    Baum3.bewegung()
    Baum3.spawn()
    Baum3.collision()









    # Maximale fps angeben
    clock.tick(60)

    # Bildschirm updaten um gezeichnete Objekte darzustellen
    pygame.display.flip()

# Pygame beenden, nachdem Haupt-Schleife beendet wurde
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It seems like you are passing the class itself, not an instance, like `Schlitten` instead of `spieler1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kollision` is an instance method. The method has to be invoked by an instance object of the class `Schlitten`. 
See further [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)  and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).
You have to pass an instance of the class `Schlitten` to the constructor of `Baum`, to solve the issue. e.g.:

```py
spieler1 = Schlitten(350,400,screen)
```

```py
Baum1 = Baum(500, 0, screen, spieler1)
Baum2 = Baum(300, -525, screen, spieler1)
Baum3 = Baum(100, -1050, screen, spieler1)
```